# SelectMany Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Could anyone explain this SelectMany Syntax

```
List<string> animals = new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "donkey" };
List<int> number = new List<int>() { 10, 20 };
var mix=number.SelectMany(num => animals, (n, a) => new { n, a });
```

I am not familiar with that syntax because I am used to use it for the purposes of flattening (to flatten a list inside list)

```
 public class x
 {
     public List<z> Zs{get; set;}
     public int Y { get; set; }
 }
 public class z
 {
     public int Y { get; set; }
 }
    List<x> Xs = new List<x>();
    Xs.Add(new x() { Zs = new List<z>() { new z() { Y = 15 } } });
    Xs.Add(new x() { Zs = new List<z>() { new z() { Y = 17 } } });
    Xs.Add(new x() { Zs = new List<z>() { new z() { Y = 19 } } });
    Xs.Add(new x() { Zs = new List<z>() { new z() { Y = 25 } } });
    Xs.Add(new x() { Zs = new List<z>() { new z() { Y = 50 } } });

Xs.SelectMany(x => x.Zs).Sum(z => z.Y);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/347/selectmany#t=201608121045348689229

Comment: Please clarify what part of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx you need help with.

Comment: If it were written as `var mix = from n in number from a in animals select new { n, a };` does that make more sense to you?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks, yeah it makes sense

Comment: @user3260672 - That is precisely the LINQ form of `number.SelectMany(num => animals, (n, a) => new { n, a });`. They are interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the reference source from Microsoft [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc79a642e00b8681)

Following is the `SelectMany` overload being utilized

```
        public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector, Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector) 
        {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            if (collectionSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("collectionSelector");
            if (resultSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("resultSelector");
            return SelectManyIterator<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(source, collectionSelector, resultSelector);
        }

        static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectManyIterator<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector, Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector) 
        {
            foreach (TSource element in source) 
            {
                foreach (TCollection subElement in collectionSelector(element)) 
                {
                    yield return resultSelector(element, subElement);
                }
            }
        }
```

**How its working** (this is also form of data flattening)

1. Similar to a concentric for / foreach loops, traversing trough two collections and creating a combined list, which has the complexity of O(N^2)
2. First we supply the number list as the `IEnumerable<TSource>`
3. Add a Func, where for each `number` we supply the `animal` list
4. Finally just get the result as the combined anonymous collection, where for each number an animal is added and thus the result is like

   ```
     n    a

     10   cat 
     10   dog 
     10   donkey 
     20   cat 
     20   dog 
     20   donkey
   ```