# C# Linq SelectMany complexity

Tags: c#, linq, code-complexity

What is the complexityclass of a Linq [Queryable.SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8).

I'm looking for [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) to predict runtime efficiency.

I checked Microsoft Docs and several other sources.

In [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053997/selectmany-linq) complexity is noted as O(N^2) what doesn't make sense to me due to probably more efficient attemps copying N memory blocks to a new connected one.

I predict the complexity to be O(N).

Can you point me to references where complexityclass for SelectMany is explicity named, or give hints why complexity is O(N^2).

Help is appreciated, Cookies for best answer.
Thanks

Comment: It operates on a collection of collections.  How is that not O(n²)?

Comment: It somewhat depends on what `n` is, since you're talking about a sequence containing sub-sequences, where each sub-sequence potentially has a different length. I'd naively say it's `O(n + Σmₜ)`, where `n` is the length of the top-level sequence, and `Σmₜ` is the sum of lengths of the sub-sequences. If each sub-sequence also has length `n`, then this becomes `O(n + n²) = O(n²)`, I would assume?

Comment: "If each sub-sequence also has length `n`" but are they related? Isn't it closer to `O(m*n)` where `m=n` may but not must be true.

Comment: @Caramiriel Each of the sub-sequences may indeed have entirely different lengths, which is that I discussed in the first part of my comment. I was trying explain where OP might have come across `O(n²)`. If each sub-sequence has length `m` then yes, `Σmₜ` is `n*m`, and so it's `O(n + n*m) = O(n*m)`, I think?