# Iterate over a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested, iterator

I'm trying to iterate through the following nested dictionary instance:

```cs
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Datetime, int>> nestedDictionary =
    new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Datetime, int>>()
```

The goal is to iterate through all integers in the dictionary. 
To iterate over the dictionary instance I use a nested `foreach` loop, as shown below:

```cs
int highestTargetInConstraint = 0;
foreach(String key1 in nestedDictionary.Keys) 
{
    foreach(int targetValue in nestedDictionary[key1].Values) 
    {
        if(targetValue > 5) { continue; }

        if(targetValue > highestTargetInConstraint)
        {
            highestTargetInConstraint = targetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the most appropriate way to loop through a flat dictionary as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary/59053661#59053661). I can't imagine to get faster than this, but maybe you can refute.

Now I'm wondering if there is a syntactically better way to loop through a nested dictionary by using a custom iterator. Useful hints and pointers to relevant documents are appreciated.

Comment: you can always use **LINQ**

Comment: I hate this "most efficient" thing. "Most appropriate" is a far better question and cannot be answered without knowing what the loop body is actually doing. Please clarify.

Comment: ...for instance, parallel linq might be a quick win here, but if you're modifying collections in the loop, maybe not. Is this loop for querying, or something more complicated?

Answer (score 2):

It is more efficient to iterate through the values directly rather than iterating through the keys and then doing an extra lookup (as in your sample code).

So this is better:

```
foreach (var dictionary in nestedDictionary.Values)
{
    foreach (int targetValue in dictionary.Values)
    {
        // Do something with targetValue
    }
}
```

Here's some test code to compare the speed with the OP:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FooBar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Dictionary<DateTime, int>>();

            int numInnerDictionaries = 5000;
            int numInnerInts         = 5000;

            for (int i = 0; i < numInnerDictionaries; ++i)
            {
                var innerDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

                var start = new DateTime(2020, 01, 01);

                for (int j = 0; j < numInnerInts; ++j)
                    innerDict.Add(start.AddSeconds(j), j);

                nestedDictionary.Add(i.ToString(), innerDict);
            }

            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int trial = 0; trial < 5; ++trial)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                method1(nestedDictionary);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("method1() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                double method1Ticks = sw.ElapsedTicks;

                sw.Restart();
                method2(nestedDictionary);
                sw.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("method2() took " + sw.Elapsed);
                Console.WriteLine($"method1() was {method1Ticks/sw.ElapsedTicks} times faster.");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static long method1(Dictionary<String, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> nestedDictionary)
        {
            long total = 0;

            foreach (var dictionary in nestedDictionary)
            {
                foreach (var item in dictionary.Value)
                {
                    total += item.Value;
                }
            }

            return total;
        }

        static long method2(Dictionary<String, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> nestedDictionary)
        {
            long result = 0;

            foreach(String key1 in nestedDictionary.Keys)
            {
                foreach(int targetValue in nestedDictionary[key1].Values)
                {
                    result += targetValue;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run a RELEASE (not DEBUG) build, it reports that the improved method is just over 3 times faster than the original method. A 3x speedup isn't too bad...

Of course, how much it is speeded up depends on how many outer dictionaries there are - the more there are, the more the speedup.

For example, if I change `numInnerDictionaries` to 50 the speedup is only around twice as fast.

Comment: ...and so commences the theatre of context-free micro-optimisation :) Focusing on these improvements without any context is... misguided.

Comment: @spender This code is both simpler and also avoids an additional lookup, so it's win/win in my opinion.

Comment: But `nestedDictionary.Values.AsParallel().SelectMany(d => d.Values)` might be a better idea. We just don't know enough about the problem domain.

Comment: @spender But what we can say with certainty is the code I posted is better than the OP's code, wouldn't you agree? Which certainly answers the OPs question of "I can't imagine to get faster than this, but maybe you can refute."

Comment: I struggle with questions that don't have an obviously correct answer. Without further clarification, these sorts of questions are more like a fishing-trip, relying on guesswork and assumptions. OP could help a lot here by adding requested clarifications. I'd be much happier to contribute myself if that were the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in LINQ. Only one line to actually do it - the rest is setup and display.

```
// Set up some data
var in1 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int> { { DateTime.Now, 1 }, { DateTime.Now, 2 }, { DateTime.Now, 3 } };
var in2 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int> { { DateTime.Now, 11 }, { DateTime.Now, 12 }, { DateTime.Now, 13 } };
var in3 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int> { { DateTime.Now, 21 }, { DateTime.Now, 22 }, { DateTime.Now, 23 } };

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, int>> nestedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, int>>
{
    { "A",in1 },
    { "B",in2 },
    { "C",in3 }
};

// Do the query
 IEnumerable<int> ints = nestedDictionary.SelectMany(n => n.Value.Select(s => s.Value));

// Show the results
foreach (int i in ints)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Refute if I'm wrong: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740662/c-sharp-linq-selectmany-complexity SelectMany offers O(N^2) complexity which is inefficient

Comment: 2) as @PeterDuniho observes, you link to an inconclusive post, which certainly suggests the performance is O(n\*m) where n\*m = N. Hence O(N).

Comment: 3) Having just done some bench-marking I get for a 1000 dictionaries each containing 1000 dictionaries (i.e 1,000,000 items in total, N=10^6) a duration of 26ms. For N=10^7, 212ms and for N=10^8, 1919ms. That looks pretty much like O(N) to me.